# how can I set the position of modal dialog in angular bootstrap ui?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to open a modal dialog at a location where the user clicked.
the modal dialog should open from a timer event, basically mouseDown start a timer, and mouseUp clear it, if enough time passed I want to open the dialog.
The dialog need to be opened at the location of the click.
I implement it all, but I do not know how to set the location of the dialog, I'm using angular bootstrap modal dialog.

any idea ?

here is a snippet of my code.

```
  var timer = null;
  var lastSceneSelectedLocation = { } ;
  // handle / prepare for context menu event
  $scope.mouseDown = function(event) {
    lastSceneSelectedLocation.x = event.clientX;
    lastSceneSelectedLocation.y = event.clientY;
    timer = window.setTimeout($scope.openSceneMenu, 1000);
    // tap and hold for 1 second to open menu
  };
  // cleanup context menu event
  $scope.mouseUp = function() {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
  };

  $scope.ScenesContextOptions = ["Move Back", "Move Forward", "Duplicate", "Delete"];
  $scope.SceneActionSelected = {};
  // context menu event
  $scope.openSceneMenu = function() {
    console.log("in scene context menu");
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'views/SceneModalDialog.html',
            scope: $scope,
            windowClass: 'sceneContextMenu'

        });

        modalInstance.opened.then(function () {
          console.log('modal opened');
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function () {
            console.log($scope.SceneActionSelected);
        }, function () {
            console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

this maybe too late but here's how to use a angular-ui-bootstrap-popover with a custom template:

**Note**: you need do download a custom [pull-request](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/1848) from angular-ui-bootstrap since the current version 0.12 doesn't support templates for popover hopefully this will be supported in [0.13](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/1848#issuecomment-66771110).

then you can do something like this:

```
<button
  class="btn btn-default"
  popover-window-placement="top"
  popover-window-trigger="click"
  popover-window="templateb.html"
>
  Popover With Template
</button>
```

**notice:** the directive is not popover anymore it's popover-window.

follow this [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/1848) for more information this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GHWf51nhijw7LdYTH0pB) shows a live example.

Answer (score 0):

I think, bootstrap's modal is not a good idea for this taks, because you can't tell him position where to open. Maybe [Popover](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/Popover) will be more suited for your task?

Comment: Do you know how can i edit a pop over to present a drop down list instead of simple text and when a user is chosen an element - i can bring it and update the my model?

Comment: @Mr.Question The only way I see - is creation of your own directive. Popover is suited for simple text only.

Answer (score 0):

A popover may satisfy your requirement.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover

I modified the example Plunker from the Angular UI Bootstrap documentation to show how you could include a list of items to select from and then identify the selected item in your controller.

```
<div ng-controller="PopoverDemoCtrl">
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <h4>Popover With Template</h4>
    <button popover-template="dynamicPopover.templateUrl" 
      popover-title="{{dynamicPopover.title}}" 
      type="button" 
      class="btn btn-default">Popover With Template</button>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myPopoverTemplate.html">
        <ul>
          <li ng-click="clickEvent(1)">Item 1</li>
          <li ng-click="clickEvent(2)">Item 2</li>
          <li ng-click="clickEvent(3)">Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </script>
</div>
```

In your controller:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('PopoverDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.dynamicPopover = {
    templateUrl: 'myPopoverTemplate.html',
    title: 'Popover With Template'
  };

  $scope.clickEvent = function (item) {
      console.log("clickEvent: " + item);
      alert("You Clicked Item: " + item);
   }; 

});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gZ3K4olmE64jvZr0yDmr)

The Plunker is here: